# How to add space to the start of byte array

Tags: java, arrays

I have this method which add spaces to the start of byte array. problem is that I am not sure if this is the most faster implementation of this task. Is there some options to add space faster ? if yes please add here some sollution

```
public static byte[] doplnMezery(byte[] item, int numberOfSpaces) {
    int lenghtOfItem = item.length;

    for (int i = lenghtOfItem; i < numberOfSpaces; i++) {
        item = ArrayUtils.add(item, 0, (byte) 32);
    }
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Often binary data is padded with `\0` instead of spaces. Does this array contain text?  Often the fastest way to do something is to avoid doing it at all. Can you not add the spaces in whatever you are passing the array to?

Comment: yes I know that 0 is usual but in requirement is space so I need to add space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems inefficient since the `add` method can't run faster than linear time. What you get here is a quadratic algorithm.

Something like this should be faster (linear time complexity).

```
public static byte[] doplnMezery(byte[] item, int numberOfSpaces) {
    byte[] result = new byte[item.length + numberOfSpaces];
    Arrays.fill(result, 0, numberOfSpaces, (byte) 32);
    System.arraycopy(item, 0, result, numberOfSpaces, item.length);        
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (JUnit test) - it *adds* 7 spaces to `items` producing `items2` array:

```
@Test
public void test1() throws Exception
{
    byte[] items = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
    byte[] items2 = new byte[3 + 7];

    System.arraycopy(items, 0, items2, 7, items.length);
    Arrays.fill(items2, 0, 7, (byte)' ');

    assertArrayEquals(new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 } , items2);
}
```